# Access base class A function by drived class B object in c#

Tags: c#, oop

Access base class A function by derived class B object in c#
 Is there is any way i can access function(Sum) of A class By B class object and get output 10.?

```
Class A
{
    public int Sum(int i)
    {
        return i+3;
    }
}

Class B:A
{
     public int Sum(int i)
     {
          return i+4;
     }
}

B objectB=new B();

int result=objectB.Sum(7);

output:11
```

Comment: Should the selection of which `Sum` method to execute be conditional or should `A`'s `sum` method always be called by `B`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare an `A` variable instead of `B`, while still using `B`'s constructor.

```
A objectB = new B();
int result=objectB.Sum(7);
```

This will use `A`'s method. This is only true because the method is shadowed and not overridden.

You will also get a compiler warning for your method `Sum` in `B` and you might want to define it as `public new int Sum(int i)` to signal that the hiding is intended.

Comment: can you let me know how can i make my oops concept strong??Thanks

Comment: I don't have any magic tricks to offer other than practicing and reading about it. It will come with experience. Don't hesitate to learn about the basics. At first you might think that you know these things already, but you'll solidify basic concepts in your mind that will help you understand more complicated ones.

Comment: I might add that this question had more to do with the `C#` language than OOP itself.